# File upload through python mechanize

Tags: python, mechanize, mechanize-python

I am trying to upload image file into the browser using mechanize.
Although there is no error, the uploaded file does not reflect when I check manually in the browser (post submit/saving). 
I am using the following code to upload the files

```
import mechanize as mc
br = mc.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.select_form(nr=0)
br.form.add_file(open("test.png"), content_type="image/png",
             filename='before',name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$fileuploadBeforeimages")

br.submit("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$cmdSave") 
# this is supposed to save the form on the webpage. It saves the texts in the other fields, whereas the image does not show up.
```

The add file command seems to work. I can confirm this because when I print `br.forms()[0]` the file details show up (`<FileControl(ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$fileuploadBeforeimages=before)>`).

But there is no sign of the image file post this code snippet. I have checked several examples which include `br.submit()` without any specific button control, when I do this no page is saved on the website.

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

## EDIT

When I manually try to upload the file, I see a pop-up asking for confirmation. Under inspect, this is present as

```
onchange="if (confirm('Upload ' + this.value + '?')) this.form.submit();"
```

I am not sure if this is a `JavaScript` element and mechanize cannot pass through this part for upload function. Can someone confirm this.?

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: No error at all. The script runs fine.

Comment: Did you try with '  ' single parenthesis? I had cases like this when it made the difference.

Comment: Tried that right now, it does not seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

you can just put 'rb' in front of image name like this:

```
br.form.add_file(open("test.png",'rb'),'images/png',filename,name='file')
```

Comment: Nope, it isn't working. Thank you for the answer though.